# Rails Geocoder Testing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-geocoder

I am trying to set up my RSpec tests to use stubs rather then using networking to do the geocoding.

I added this:

```
before(:each) do
Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)
Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(
    "Los Angeles, CA", [{
                            :latitude    => 34.052363,
                            :longitude    => -118.256551,
                            :address      => 'Los Angeles, CA, USA',
                            :state        => 'California',
                            :state_code   => 'CA',
                            :country      => 'United States',
                            :country_code => 'US'
                        }],

)
```

end

I am using FactoryGirl to create the test data like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :market do
    city 'Los Angeles'
    state 'CA'
    radius 20.0
  end
end
```

The latitude/longitude are correctly being geocoded and stored in latitude/longitude. However, when I try:

```
Market.near(params[:search])
```

it returns nil.. But, if I just use the lookup => :google it works just as I intend it to. Has anyone got this working before, specifically the near method of geocoder?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am running into the exact same issue now

Comment: @AlexNeigher See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up coming back to this on a new project and figured it out.

The docs on geocoder actually state that the hash has to have string keys and not symbols. [geocoder docs - see notes](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#testing-apps-that-use-geocoder)

i.e.

```
before(:each) do
    Geocoder.configure(:lookup => :test)
    Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(
        "Los Angeles, CA", [{
                                "latitude"    => 34.052363,
                                "longitude"    => -118.256551,
                                "address"      => 'Los Angeles, CA, USA',
                                "state"        => 'California',
                                "state_code"   => 'CA',
                                "country"      => 'United States',
                                "country_code" => 'US'
                            }],

    )
end
```

and not how I did it in the original post:

i.e. `:latitude => 34.052363`

I ended up doing something a bit more dynamic:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module GeocoderStub
  def self.stub_with(facility)
    Geocoder.configure(lookup: :test)

    results = [
      {
          'latitude' => Faker::Address.latitude.first(9),
          'longitude' => Faker::Address.longitude.first(9)
      }
    ]

    queries = [facility.full_address, facility.zip]
    queries.each { |q| Geocoder::Lookup::Test.add_stub(q, results) }
  end
end
```

and in my factory:

```
require './spec/support/geocoder_stub'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :facility do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    rating { rand(1..5) }
    street { Faker::Address.street_address }
    city { Faker::Address.city }
    state { Faker::Address.state }
    zip { Faker::Address.zip_code }

    after(:build) { |facility| GeocoderStub.stub_with(facility) }
  end
end
```

This adds a geocoder stub for every Facility factory that is built for both full address (method defined in facility) and zip.

Comment: :heart: :heart: :heart:

Comment: the best solution is using [`vcr`](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to stub all http requests

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler approach to be just stubbing everything with the same values by default:

```rb
# test/test_helper.rb
Geocoder.configure(lookup: :test)
Geocoder::Lookup::Test.set_default_stub([{ coordinates: [40.7143528, -74.0059731] }])
```

Also, to avoid unnecessary calls, it's also a good idea to restrict your callbacks:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj) { obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
end
```

Source: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#testing